# why get the wrong week display name from unix timestamp in Java

Tags: java

Now I am using this Java code to get weeks display name:

```
String dateTime = CustomDatetimeUtil.timeStamp2Date(response.getStatisticTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
                response.setStatisticDate(dateTime);
                String displayName = Instant.ofEpochSecond(response.getStatisticTime())
                        .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai"))
                        .getDayOfWeek()
                        .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.CHINA);
```

the `response.getStatisticTime()` value is `1614783599999`. But I get the display name is · `Sunday(星期日)`. the correct value is wednesday. what should I do to get the right value?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using [`Instant.ofEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond(long))- but the value you've got is large enough that it's presumably the number of [*milliseconds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) since the Unix [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)), not the number of *seconds*.

So basically you need to use [`Instant.ofEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli(long)) instead.

I would recommend using the [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) site in future too - that allows you to put in a numeric value, and it will show you what that value means *including the units it has assumed when performing the conversion*.